# Remove RPM package without boot (via LiveDVD boot)

Tags: linux, kernel, rpm

I've installed a RPM (MySQL Shared glibc Library). After that I couldn't boot my fedora Linux box (Because of some crash with kernel glibc). I boot via LiveDVD and renamed the RPM's copied files, but it can't solved.
How can I uninstall my RPM (not only files) through other Linux or Live CD?

Comment: Installing that package would not cause the system to fail in that way.

Comment: After installing glibc I receive Memory problem with libc.so.6. I think that is because of installing that. How can I see what did RPM installing (rpm -ivh)?

Answer (score 1):

If you boot from a live cd you can remove rpm packages from the installed system by running

```
rpm --erase --root /mnt/your_system_mount_point the-package-you-want-to-remove
```

Another alternatively is boot the system by editing the boot loader kernel command line to contain `init=/bin/bash` and try to run `rpm --erase the-package-you-want-to-remove` from there. If the problem is with glibc you might have trouble getting bash executed (as well as rpm), but you might want to try this option as well just to see how far the startup is progressing without problems. Thinking of it, busybox usually comes with a statically linked binary that could be used as init shell, you might have better success using that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, hlovdal. I tried both way but no response. The firs show that the RPM isn't installed on the system. It seem it check with LiveCD not mounted HDD. The second way can't help to up.

Comment: The error that I see in boot time is: /lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_out_of_memory, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2

Comment: /lib/ld-linux.so.2 is part of the glibc rpm package. Maybe you could try to boot live cd, download a glibc rpm file (corresponding to the glibc version that is installed), convert the rpm to a cpio file, extract files from that and then overwrite at least /lib/ld-linux.so.2 with the file from those extracted files. Those files should be working fine together. Probably a good idea to take backup of the original files before overwriting them.

Comment: Thank you my friend. According to your recommend I removed /lib/tls content and restart and my problem is solved now :)